# Numbers and Sections Options altering layout upon changing page number

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to add page numbers to a glossary I am making. While i am getting the page numbers to appear. I now am trying to make it so the page numbering will start on page 2, rather than the cover page, and will start with the number 1. But each time I try to do it, the layout gets rearranged like so-

[image: arrangement 1]
If I try to move the pages, it only allows me to arrange them like this.

[image: arrangement 2]
What am I doing wrong? I used this video for help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg7DtSQECOk but still, no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These screenshots are from InDesign CC, but should be similar to your version of InDesign.

Please start with the pages flowing the default way InDesign sets them (first page is page number 1). The triangle above the first page indicates that a section starts there.
[image: Starting state of pages]

Next, select pages 2-3 by `shift-clicking` them individually. Then, `right-click` that spread, and uncheck "Allow Selected Spreads to Shuffle".
[image: Locking the spread]

You'll notice there are brackets around pages 2-3 now indicating they are locked together.
[image: Spread locked]

Then select page 2, and `right-click` again and select "Numbering & Section Options". From the box that comes up, select "Start Page Numbering at", and make sure it is set to "1". Then click `OK` and `OK` again to accept duplicate page numbers.
[image: Numbering & Section Options]

Success! Your page number 1 is now a left hand spread.
[image: Success]

---

**Optional Step Zero:** To avoid the duplicate page numbers warning at the end, you can insert this step at the beginning:
Select page 1, `right-click` it, and select "Numbering & Section Options". Then from the `Style` pull-down, choose a different page numbering method, such as Roman numerals.
[image: Roman Numerals]

Comment: An alternative is to turn off "Allow Document Pages to Shuffle" after doing your Step Zero. This creates the same result.

Comment: True @AlanGilbertson , but doesn't that essentially turn the document in to _n_ sheets, and break any document flow? It seems like it could get [very confusing](http://imgur.com/2tzgw38) if you need to reorder your pages, or add/remove pages.

Comment: Not unless you specifically export spreads (a handy way to do foldouts, which is what you're thinking of, but not the only case). I've not come across confusion with it, once it's understood. On the other hand, I'd also never put an even numbered folio on a recto, even in a pamphlet. :/

Comment: I managed to figure it out on my own, but this answer is super indepth and will help others I work with who didn't know how to fix the problem. Thank you @apex!